# 165hz doesn't show

Tags: graphics, screen

My screen is 165hz and it doesn't show in the settings. I have the latest Nvidia drivers installed.

Output of xrandr:

[image: output of xrandr]

Answer (score 1):

you can set it in .xinitrc with

xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 165

hope this helps.
let me know if you face any issue.